# Two Layer Binding in Textbox is not writing

Tags: wpf

I think I may be using the DependencyObject incorrectly.

I have a generic class that implements the DependencyObject called Person with the properties FirstName and LastName.

```
public class Person : DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty FirstNameProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("FirstName", typeof(string), typeof(Person));

    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(FirstNameProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FirstNameProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty LastNameProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("LastName", typeof(string), typeof(Person));

    public string LastName
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(LastNameProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LastNameProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

Then I have a xaml control with its datacontext set to my ViewModel class.  Inside the ViewModel class I have a property called UserName that gets/sets a Person.  The text box is bound to the UserName.FirstName property.  It can populate the textbox correctly but can't seem to call the set when I enter characters and tab out.  I think the issue is the two level property binding.  For design reasons I need to access it through two levels of properties.  Any suggestions?

Here is my xaml:

```
<TextBox Width="100" Margin="10,0,0,0" Text="{Binding Path=UserName.FirstName, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Here is my property in the view model class:

```
    public Person UserName
    {
        get
        {
            return person;
        }
        set
        {
            person = value;
        }
    }
```

I've also tried it this way too:

```
    public Person UserName
    {
        get
        {
            return person;
        }
        set
        {
            person.FirstName = value.FirstName;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry for offtopic, why you called property of type `Person` as `UserName` and not simply `User`, it is slightly confusing

Comment: Did a test with your code and it worked for me first time... Added a callback to the properties so I saw the value changing ¿could it be something else?

Comment: Really?  What do you mean as adding a callback to the properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your property will not be called from the binding, the property is only there because of the pattern so it is easily visible from code. 
The binding sets the dependency property directly.

Why do you want dependency properties in this situation? Dependency properties are relevant on controls - for your scenario use regular properties and INotifyPropertyChanged - the code will be simpler that way :)

If you do want notification when a dependencyproperty is changed you have to add a static eventhandler to the  DependencyProperty.Register(...) call.

Comment: I see.  I've been going down the wrong path.  Don't know if INotifyPropertyChanged will help me.  I've place breakpoints on the set inside UserName property and the program doesn't even break.  I've looked at the output window and I don't see any errors printing out.  Would you be able to give me a sample snippet of how you would use INotifyPropertyChanged in this situation.  I've used INotifyPropertyChanged only when I need to tell the usercontrol that I've changed data.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with rune Andersen.
You should use INotifyPropertyChanged.

```
public class Person :INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        private string _firstName;
        public string FirstName
        {
            get { return _firstName; }
            set { _firstName = value; OnPropertyChanged("FirstName"); }
        }
        private string _lastName;
        public string LastName
        {
            get { return _lastName; }
            set { _lastName = value; OnPropertyChanged("LastName"); }
        }


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }
        }
    }
```